# python - Lookup from a RDD inside a map of another RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have 2 RDD:

- RDD1 = (word, score) #word: string | score: int
- RDD2 = (id, text) #id: int | text: list of words

so for each 'id' in RDD2 I want to calculate the mean of score for each word in text if it has score

```
def predecir(texto): 
    contador = 0    
    prediccion = 0
    for palabra in texto:
        puntaje = listaRDD.lookup(palabra)
        if puntaje:
                puntaje = puntaje[0]
                prediccion += puntaje
                contador += 1
    return (float(prediccion)/ contador)

listaTestRDD = listaTestRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0], predecir(x[1])))
print listaTestRDD.take(1)
```

And I get this error message

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or
>   reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations
>   and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

How can I do to solve it? I can´t use two RDD one inside the other? How can I convert the RDD1 to a dictionary in order to find a word in O(1)?

Comment: So what is the question? Error message is clear.

Comment: @LostInOverflow how can I do to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RDD2.flatMapValues(lambda x: x) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) \
    .leftOuterJoin(RDD1) \
    .values() \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], 1) if x[1] is not None else (0, 0))) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1])) \
    .mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / float(x[1]) if x[1] else 0.0)
```